# Setting image require path dynmanically

Tags: react-native

In react native navigation I use a custom icon, I want to be able to change this icon depending on if the user is in dark mode or normal mode.

The challenge I'm having is passing in the value of the path dynamically. I want to call a method inline that returns the file name of the icon.

```
<Marker
  coordinate={this.state.region}
  image={require("./" + {chkDarkMode()} + ".png")}
/>
```

How can I dynamically set the image? I've seen the conditional if length is equal to zero, but that example doesn't allow for multiple possible images.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's not allowed.

You can instead call `require` conditionally:

`const image = darkMode ? require("./darkModeImage.png") : require("./lightModeImage.png")`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this:

```
getImagePath = () => {
   return `./${chkDarkMode()}.png`
}

<Marker
coordinate={this.state.region}
image={getImagePath()}
/>
```